# Fix for "TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object" when using Python Multiprocessing in a Class

Tags: python, class, multiprocessing, fastapi

I am currently working on a Python FastAPI application that spawns busy loops in parallel threads using the multiprocessing library. When I first started building the application, I created the threads during start-up in the main.py file. This worked great and I could spawn all the threads I needed with no issues.

Eventually I needed specific FastAPI endpoints to also be able to control those threads, so instead of spawning the threats on application startup, I created a singleton class file that could control the threads and be accessed by both the startup process and by  FastAPI endpoints.

The issue is that as soon as I moved the Process method from the main.py file to the .core.thread_utils.py file, I now get the following error when I spawn more than one thread:

```
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 677, in lifespan
    async with self.lifespan_context(app) as maybe_state:
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 566, in __aenter__
    await self._router.startup()
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 654, in startup
    await handler()
  File "/home/user/Projects/test/test-api/api/main.py", line 127, in startup_event
    thread_utils.launch_all_threads()
  File "/home/user/Projects/test/test-api/api/core/thread_utils.py", line 66, in launch_all_threads
    p.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/context.py", line 284, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 32, in __init__
    super().__init__(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 19, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py", line 47, in _launch
    reduction.dump(process_obj, fp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object
```

So, the code that worked fine in main.py, as soon as it's put into a separate class, now throws an error. Also, I can spawn **one** thread with no issues at all, but **more than one** thread throws the 'cannot pickle' TypeError. I do not understand why.

After some research on specifically how Python forks new threads, I believe I am hitting [this error](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/91090). Also, the multiprocessing documentation mentions '[safe importing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods)' but I'm not sure if/how that applies to this situation because attempts to apply this produce the same error or no threads at all. I could be doing that wrong...

The code I'm using looks something like this:

**main.py:**

```
from .core.thread_utils import thread_utils
thread_utils = thread_utils()
...
@app.on_event("startup") # this is part of FastAPI
async def startup_event():
    # previous thread creation went here and worked perfectly
    thread_utils.launch_all_threads()
```

**core/thread_utils.py:**

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from ..core import busy_loop

class thread_utils:
    _self = None

    def __new__(cls):
        if cls._self is None:
            cls._self = super().__new__(cls)
            return cls._self

    def launch_runner_thread(self, t:int):
        busy_loop(t)

    def launch_all_threads(self):
        t_list = [1,2]
        for t in t_list:
            p = Process(target=self.launch_runner_thread, args=(t,))
            p.start()
```

Any help, direction, or working examples of how to implement multiprocessing in a separate class would be very appreciated!

**WORKING CODE** (thanks to @pts' suggestion below!)

**main.py**

```
from .core.thread_utils import launch_all_threads
...
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    launch_all_threads()
```

**core/thread_utils.py:**

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from ..core import busy_loop

def launch_runner_thread(t:int):
    busy_loop(t)

def launch_all_threads():
    t_list = [1,2]
    for t in t_list:
        p = Process(target=launch_runner_thread, args=(t,))
        p.start()
```

I will go ahead and update the title of this question to match the problem/solution and give @pts the credit for answering. Thank you again!

Comment: Where are you creating the thread_utils() object?  You've got all these instance methods, but you're calling them as if they were static methods.

Comment: You keep SAYING "threads" but your code is creating processes.  Are you sure you understand the difference?  Because they are quite different concepts.

Comment: @FrankYellin Sorry, I was trying to keep the code simple but I can see how not seeing required things like that would be annoying. thread_utils() is instantiated right after it's imported. I've added it to the sample code. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @TimRoberts You are correct. Apologies for the poor terminology. I'm using processes specifically because I need true parallel processes for this use-case. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: Please don't abbreviate (`...`) the traceback of the original exception. Each line there can be relevant.

Comment: It would probably be helpful to see the old working code (and generally to have a reproducible example of each state).

Comment: @pts I've updated the above to include the part I abbreviated. Thank you for looking!

Comment: @DavisHerring I working on that now actually in an attempt to isolate the problem further on my own. Basically, the code in the launch_all_threads was on it's own (not in a method) in that spot in main.py and it worked like I needed it to. I just can't access it from the endpoints from there! =\ Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `self.` from the `Process(target=self....)` call, and move the called function outside the class. This should solve the TypeError.

Comment: I get "NameError: Name 'launch_runner_thread' is not defined." without specifying 'self' there.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, move the function (`def`) outside the class. This will fix the NameError. Also remove the `self,` argument.

Comment: That was it. Thank you brother. ::sensai bow::